# Web service calls failing on remote server

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

I've got a webservice called Converter.asmx and I've just noticed that on the remote server I basically can't connect to it. The error that I get: `"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:49792"` and the error occurs where I'm calling the web service (second line below).

```
Dim webservice As New localhost.Converter
results.InnerHtml = webservice.ParseData(txtInput.InnerText, options)
```

On my localhost it works fine. How can I change the webservice so that it'll work on the remote host as well?

Comment: Is the web service running on port 49792 on your shared host? Because that is what the error message is telling me.

Comment: The port is an remnant of my testing on the local server as kprobst pointed out.

Comment: If you make Radu's changes, does the problem go away?

Comment: See my latest comment - it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a firewall or IP restriction of some kind blocking the call.

Comment: If there is one I have no control over it since the remote server is on shared hosting.

Comment: Wait, if this is your deployed service running on shared hosting why are you hitting the `127.0.0.1:49792` endpoint? Shouldn't you be configuring it to be something like `http://example.com/foo.asmx`?

Comment: Do I need to change the .disco file to reflect that?

Comment: No, typically with ASMX what you can do is create an instance of the generated service reference class, and then override its Url property prior to calling it, which you normally get from your web.config file or some other location.

Comment: So in my case it should be something like `webservice.Url = "http://example.com/foo.asmx`. Is it a good idea to combine that with something like `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` to determined whether or not the URL needs to be changed?

Comment: In this case the debugging part won't be particularly useful since an inability to connect is fairly obvious.

Comment: Fixed, just changed the setting in web.config though I tried doing it programatically and that works too. Thanks!